# show last last_autovacuum/anaylze etc based on the 20 biggest tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, datadog

I'm trying to monitor our postgresql DB and identify the 20 largest tables and than see when was the last vacuum and analyse took place.

I have this query that shows me the largest 20 schema name/relname which is good and that's what I was looking for:

```
SELECT schema_name, relname, pg_size_pretty(table_size) AS size, table_size 
FROM ( SELECT pg_catalog.pg_namespace.nspname  AS schema_name,relname, 
pg_relation_size(pg_catalog.pg_class.oid) AS table_size FROM 
pg_catalog.pg_class JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ON relnamespace = 
pg_catalog.pg_namespace.oid ) t WHERE schema_name NOT LIKE 'pg_%' ORDER BY 
table_size DESC LIMIT 20;
```

I also have this query that shows me all the analysis I want to see with schema name and relname:

```
select relname, schemaname, last_vacuum, last_autovacuum, last_analyze, last_autoanalyze from pg_stat_user_tables;
```

But I'm having a real hard time combining them together to one query that will show me when those analysis only for those 20 tables.

Once this is done I'm looking to view the results in some sort of a graphic view in datadog, so If anyone have a good idea how to run this query as a datadog posgres query it will be amazing as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone will need the answer, this is how I did this.
It shows the biggest tables that were not last vacuumed in that past 2 weeks, but limits the list for 20 results.

If you want to you can change LIMIT 20 or delete it for shorter/longer list. Also change pg.last_autovacuum for analyze or anything else from pg.stat table you want to check and also 2 week can be changed to whatever time period you want.

```
SELECT t.nspname || '.' || t.relname AS "relation", size, count(DISTINCT t.relname)
from (SELECT nspname, relname, pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(C.oid)) AS "size"
      FROM pg_class C
         LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace)
      WHERE nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
      ORDER BY pg_relation_size(C.oid) DESC
      LIMIT 20) t
       left join pg_stat_user_tables pg on pg.relname = t.relname
where pg.last_autovacuum < now() - interval '2 week'
group by relation, size;
```

Answer (score 0):

In datadog under postgres.yaml I added this:

```
custom_metrics:
- # Last Auto vacuum tables
  query: SELECT t.nspname || '.' || t.relname AS "relation", size, %s from (SELECT nspname , relname , pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(C.oid)) AS "size" FROM pg_class C LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON ( N.oid = C.relnamespace) WHERE nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema') ORDER BY pg_relation_size(C.oid) DESC LIMIT 20) t left join pg_stat_user_tables pg on pg.relname = t.relname where pg.last_autovacuum < now() - interval '2 week' group by relation, size;
  metrics:
      count(DISTINCT t.relname) last_autovacuum: [postgresql.last_autovacuum, GAUGE]
  relation: false
  descriptors:
      - [relation, relation]
      - [size, size]
```

Then I added this as a top-list inside a dashboard. You can also make it as an alert and sum up the counts inside the metrics and decide what's your limit that about it you want to start vacuuming, although it's just recommended to run it regularly and not just when it's just too big, that's why we use this only as a list in our dashboard. To get eyes only.